# Что возвращает substring(0, 0)

Tags: java

Хотелось бы узнать: какую строку возвращает `substring(0, 0)`, если вызывающая строка состоит только из одного символа?

```
String s1 = "W";
String s2 = s1.substring(0, 0);
```

Чему равна `s2`?

Comment: почему просто не выполнить этот код и не посмотреть?

Comment: потому что компилятор ругается, и я не понимаю логики его недовольства

Comment: ну если код не компилируется, то однозначно ничего не вернется

Comment: код компилируется, но с правками
если перед переменными поставить модификатор static, то при выводе s2 через println просто ничего не выводится ( ну тоесть пустая строка ), вопрос почему именно нужен модификатор static

Comment: а у меня не ругается :-) может стоит хотя бы ошибку привести, которую он выводит?

Comment: @Archaea потому что наверное строка объявлена в классе, а выполнять пытаешься в статическом методе..... привел бы свой код и ошибку - тебе бы сказали точнее...... а то ошибка одна, а спрашиваешь совсем о другом.

Comment: Либо у вас неправильный компилятор и он делает неправильный скомпилированный код, либо вы всё же что-то утаиваете от общественности. Указанный в вопросе код вполне нормально компилируется и работает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам вернется пустая строка. При чем не `null`, а просто `new String("")`.

Answer (score 5):

В таких случаях всегда открывайте документацию метода. И смотрите его исходный код и логику работы. Из исходников.

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > value.length) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
            : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

`value` это ссылка на массив символов которые хранит ваша строка

Answer (score 1):

Метод substring(n, m) возвращает подстроку начиная с n индекса (включая) до m индекса (не включая).
В нашем случае substring(0, 0) возвращает пустую строку, как при инициализации новой переменной:
String s2 = "";

Наглядно это можно продемонстрировать следующим кодом.
При сравнении s2 и "" equals возвращает true.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "W";
    String s2 = s1.substring(0, 0);
    System.out.println(s2.equals(""));}
true
```